Uninstalling the old Ubuntu on Windows app after installing new Ubuntu app in Microsoft Store
I had been using the old Ubuntu on Windows app from Microsoft Store since WSL2 was released on Windows 10. Just a week ago I found out that Canonical had released a newer "Ubuntu" app some time ago, so I installed that as well, but the weird thing is that the two Ubuntu apps actually seem to share their binaries.
Is it still safe to uninstall the older Ubuntu on Windows app?

It is safe to uninstall the older Ubuntu on Windows app if you have already installed the newer Ubuntu app from Microsoft Store.
Before you uninstall the older Ubuntu on Windows app follow these steps to make sure that uninstalling the older app will not disrupt your workflow or cause any data loss.

List your WSL instances in cmd.exe (aka cmd window) or PowerShell with wsl -l -v to verify that your Ubuntu installation is intact. wsl -l -v (or the equivalent command wsl --list --verbose) lists all the installed WSL distributions with a little bit of information about each one. The fact that you still only see one "Ubuntu" entry (the newest one) when you run wsl -l -v indicates that your Ubuntu instance has safely upgraded from "Ubuntu on Windows" from Canonical Group Limited to "Ubuntu" from Canonical Group Limited (the same source) without any problem.

Open the new Ubuntu app, and check that everything works and that your data is accessible.

If you notice anything wrong in step 2, back up any important files or configurations from your WSL instance before continuing.



That fact that I still only see one "Ubuntu" entry when I run wsl -l -v makes it ever more worrisome.
